# Can I get a person's display name or composite name from AddressBook on OS X?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, abaddressbook

I have come across `ABRecordCopyCompositeName()` in these pages but, having Spotlighted it, have a hunch it's only available for the iOS platform. The AddressBook app itself, and `ABPeoplePicker` obviously do something similar internally, so is there an equivalent API for OS X? It's a tedious thing to retrieve title, first name, middle name, last name, suffix and work out if it's a company before building it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately as you've surmised, `ABRecordCopyCompositeName` is only available on iOS as of this writing. There does not appear to be equivalent public API in OS X.

Answer (score 0):

`ABPerson`'s superclass `ABRecord` has the `displayName` property which is exactly what we need.